# Почему не выполняется условие if else в javascript?

Tags: javascript, условия, if

Добрый день. Я только разбираюсь с `JavaScript`, пробую написать простой скрип с условиями. Но по факту условия считываются неправильно - при любых входных данных скрип выдает результат последнего условия `(('1 (Scalene)')`. 
Помогите разобраться где у меня ошибка! Спасибо!

```js
function displayResult() {
  var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  var c = document.getElementById('c').value;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = calculateResult(a, b, c);
}


function calculateResult() {
  if (a == b && b == c) {
    return ('3 (Equilateral)')
  } else if (a >= (b + c) || c >= (b + a) || b >= (a + c)) {
    return ('4 (Error. Not a triangle)')
  } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (a != b && c == a) || (c == b && c != a)) {
    return ('2 (Isosceles)')
  } else if (a != b && b != c && c != a) {
    return ('1 (Scalene)')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" placeholder="Side a">
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" placeholder="Side b">
<input type="text" name="c" id="c" placeholder="Side c">
<input type="button" id="calculate" onclick="displayResult()" value="Triangle type">
<br>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: проверь чем на самом деле являются переменные a,b,c внутри calculateResult

Answer (score 4):

Не работает, потому что `calculateResult()` определена без использования переменных и заданные a, b, c в ней не используются, а используются какие-то другие переменные с неизвестными значениями.

Исправьте строчку `function calculateResult()` на `function calculateResult(a, b, c)`:

```js
function displayResult() {
  var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  var c = document.getElementById('c').value;

  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = calculateResult(Number(a), Number(b), Number(c));
}


function calculateResult(a, b, c) {
  if (a == b && b == c) {
    return ('3 (Equilateral)')
  } else if (a >= (b + c) || c >= (b + a) || b >= (a + c)) {
    return ('4 (Error. Not a triangle)')
  } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (a != b && c == a) || (c == b && c != a)) {
    return ('2 (Isosceles)')
  } else if (a != b && b != c && c != a) {
    return ('1 (Scalene)')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="a" id="a" placeholder="Side a">
<input type="text" name="b" id="b" placeholder="Side b">
<input type="text" name="c" id="c" placeholder="Side c">
<input type="button" id="calculate" onclick="displayResult()" value="Triangle type">
<br>
<p id="result"></p>
```

---

Как справедливо заметили в комментариях, чтобы сравнение работало правильно, нужно значения переменных перевести в  числа. Например, при вызове функции:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = calculateResult(Number(a), Number(b), Number(c));
```

Comment: значения известны: это сами элементы с такими `id`

Comment: Спасибо, сработало )))  Но теперь кроме условия "3 (Equilateral)" для всех других комбинаций данных выдает "4 (Error. Not a triangle)"

Comment: @TattyQ, потому что надо перед передачей в функцию в числа переводить, иначе результат сложения может удивить

Comment: Все теперь работает. Большое спасибо!!!